# CSS element "Background" giving div tag image source

Tags: css

I am not sure I explained my problem well enough in the title. 
I'm trying to add 'small arrows' next to menu links and when I hover them, they move+change color. I'm developing in Brackets and everything worked perfectly, I didn't need any Javascript, everything was done by CSS. Then I tryed to open the html file directly in browser and some of the images from the folder (the arrows) do not appear. I also tryed the same using WebMatrix and the result was the same. Background and Logo images, from the same folder as arrows, appear, but that is all. When I changed the Background Url in CSS to full path C://../../arrow-right.png then they appeared in Webmatrix and browser directly but not when opened via Brackets.

The HTML part

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="images/Logo.png" alt="logo"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">The Product</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Order Yours</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Support 
    <div class="rectangle">.<div class="arrow-down">.</div></div> 
   </a>
   <div id="sub-menu">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Read our FAQ <div class="arrow-right">.</div></a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Post a Support Ticket <div class="arrow-right">.</div></a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Orders &amp; Shipping <div class="arrow-right">.</div></a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Get in touch with us</a></li>
```

And the CSS:

```css
    .arrow-right {
        color: transparent;
        position: absolute;
        top: 19px;
        right: -200px;
        background: url(images/arrow-right.png) no-repeat;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .rectangle {
        color: transparent;
        width: 15px;
        height: 80px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: url(images/Background.png);
        z-index: 1; 
    }

    .arrow-down {
        background: url(images/arrow-down.png) no-repeat;
        color: transparent;
        position: relative;
        top: 20px;
        width: 8px;
        height: 6px;
        left: 4px;
    }
```

Also I tryed to add the background image directly into div tags and edited only its position, that way the arrow images showed up aswell, but I would not be able to move/change color without Javascript.

I understand that you don't see any of the images but I am hoping that someone has any idea why it acts like that.

Why does only Brackets understand the Background: url(..) in CSS but others need it in the div style directly? I'm really confused about the weird acts.

Comment: can you show us the root content so that we can check the URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Brackets, there is a built in previewer so even the relative paths work.

For viewing in browser, you need to specify the full path because it doesn't run on server to automatically calculate the full path.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the quick answer, I guess i'll just keep the relative paths while developing then. Its still weird why Brackets doesn' t understand the full path like browser/WebMatrix tho.